# React native tipsi stripe error You should call init first

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm using `tipsi-stripe' for payment but when click submit it's showing error` You should call init first`
below is my code

```
setIsLoading(true);
            const aa = await stripe.createTokenWithCard({
              cvc: "123", 
              expMonth: 11, 
              expYear: 2022,
              number: "4242424242424242",
            });
            if (aa) {
              console.log(aa.tokenId);
              setModal(false);
            } else {
              setIsLoading(true);
            }
```

can someone please tell me why it's showing this error please?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't init the package correctly: https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/usage.html